# Sorting through a two dimensional array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a 2D array in php which holds the date:

```
$cal[$year][$month] = $event;
```

Output of the array is:

```
Array ( [2012] => Array ( [6] => 10.92 [11] => 16.38 [8] => 1.3 [9] => 16.96 )
```

I would like to sort the array by year and month. How do I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: have u tried sort() functions?

Comment: check this, http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: take a look at the array_multisort function

Answer (score 1):

you should look to the array_multisort function, you can find informations here:
 http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

the second example is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

According to your following array:

```
$cal[$year][$month] = $event;
```

and taking into account that `$year` and `$month` are both numeric (if not, just cast them).

For ordering both years and months in ASCENDING order, do:

```
ksort($cal); //sort years
foreach($cal as &$arr) {
   ksort($arr); //sort months
}
```

if you want it in DESCENDING order, do:

```
krsort($cal); //sort years
foreach($cal as &$arr) {
   krsort($arr); //sort months
}
```

you can interchange `ksort()` and `krsort()` in both examples if you want a mix sort, like years ASCENDING and months DESCENDING.